# SQL Query - records within the last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Bit of a complicated one for me.

I have a database full of hundreds of thousands of records, many of which are duplicated.

I need to get all records within the last year but making sure every instance of that record is within the last year, e.g. if a record is duplicated and one is older than a year this shouldn't be included.

So far I have the below...

Step 1 - find out earliest date for each record

```
SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS Date, Email FROM Results R
WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
GROUP BY R.Email
```

I created this as a view and called it `[EarliestInteraction]`

Step 2 - grab all within the last year

Note: I need records within the last year but they also need to be in a log table also. So all records within the last year that are also present in some log tables.

So far I have done this...

```
SELECT * FROM EarliestInteraction ECI
WHERE ( CAST(ECI.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() - 365 AS DATE) )
AND (

    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG1 R
        WHERE Source = 'LOGGED'
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
    )

    OR

    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG2 R WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
            AND R.EventType IN (
            'LOGGED'
    ))
)
```

My question is, is this a good way of doing this and accurate?

Or am I missing something that would bring back earlier duplicates...

Any thoughts on if this is accurate or achieves the brief would be great.

Answer (score 2):

## The following are a few suggestions on how I'd write your view.

**Source Control**

If you don't already have a [database project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272677(v=vs.103)), create one in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). Then check it in to source control. [Microsoft Azure DevOps Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/devops/) is free & private for teams of 5 or less (this is per project, so 5 developers per project). Then you'll be able to track changes you make to your stored procedures, views, tables, etc.

**Formatting**

I would download the following tool for SSMS and Visual Studio, [Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TaoKlerks.PoorMansT-SqlFormatterSSMSVSExtension) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter). I use it when I have to edit other developer's code. It's a great way to standardize your SQL. I find it does most of the formatting for me, but I'll still make a few changes after.

Here are the settings I used:

[image: screenshot]

**Commas**

I would put the commas in front to clearly define new columns. Versus code wrapped in multiple lines. It also makes trouble-shooting code easier.

**Where Clause**

If you put `1=1` at the top of a `WHERE` condition, it enables you to freely change the rest of the conditions when debugging a query. The SQL query engine will end up ignoring the `1=1` so it should have no performance impact. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242822/9059424)

**Common Table Expressions (CTE)**

[CTE's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your SQL help with documentation. The expression name can then let other developers know why you used that expression e.g. `current_suppliers` or `active_projects`.

**Schema Names**

Always reference the schema when selecting an object e.g. `[dbo].[SalesTable]`.

**Estimated Execution Plan**

It's a good idea to check the [Estimated Execution Plan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017). The shortcut in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. You can even run 2 queries in the same tab to compare the plans.

**Keywords**

Avoid using keywords as object names. [Microsoft Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

- Also check out the book [*Clean Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882). It will change the way you think about naming conventions.

---

**Revised SQL**

Without table definitions and sample records I was unable to test this, but it should give you a good start.

```
WITH
earliest_interaction
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [min_createdate] = CAST(MIN(r.[CreateDate]) AS DATE)
        , r.[Email]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Results] AS r
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND (r.[Email] IS NOT NULL AND r.[Email] != '')
    GROUP BY 
        r.[Email]
)
,
log_files
AS
(
    SELECT [Email] FROM [dbo].[LOG1] WHERE [Source] = 'LOGGED'
    UNION
    SELECT [Email] FROM [dbo].[LOG2] WHERE [Source] = 'LOGGED'
)
SELECT 
      ei.[min_createdate]
    , ei.[Email]
FROM 
    earliest_interaction AS ei
    INNER JOIN log_files AS lf ON lf.[Email] = ei.[Email]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND (ei.[min_createdate] >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your view does not filter on the most recent year.

> ```
> SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS Date, Email FROM Results R
> WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
> GROUP BY R.Email
> ```

This filter does not change that because your view has already grouped results taking into account data older than 1 year.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM EarliestInteraction ECI
> WHERE ( CAST(ECI.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() - 365 AS DATE) )
> ..
> ```

You don't need a view, just a CTE.

```
with (SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS Date, Email 
      FROM Results R
      WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
      -- add the filter before the GroupBy !
      AND ( CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) >= Cast(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) as Date) )
      GROUP BY R.Email) as ECI
select *
from ECI
where (
    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG1 R
        WHERE Source = 'LOGGED'
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
    )
    OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG2 R WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
            AND R.EventType IN (
            'LOGGED'
    ))
);
```

Or in short

```
   with (SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS Date, Email 
          FROM Results R
          WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
          -- add the filter before the GroupBy !
          AND ( CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) >= Cast(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) as Date) )
          GROUP BY R.Email) as ECI
    select *
    from ECI
    inner join LOG1 r1 on r1.Email = ECI.Email and r1.Source = 'LOGGED'
    inner join LOG2 r2 on r2.Email = ECI.Email and r2.Source = 'LOGGED'
    ;
```